# How to copy files from GitHub action server(Ubuntu tunner) to AWS ec2 instance(centos) remotly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I created the pipeline in GitHub action to get code, build and deploy NodeJS application for AWS LightSail instance. Pulling the code and building it was successful, but I want to copy the built files to an AWS ec2 instance. But it cant be done.

I used the ubuntu server runner hosted by GitHub. I need to copy the all files in built folder in GitHub server to AWS LightSail instance have pem file for the AWS server. I copied that pem file key and configured it as a repository secrets in GitHub (SSH_PRIVATE_KEY). but when I run the action it gives the error.

Pipeline

```
name: Deployment QA UI
on: push
jobs:
    Get_code: 
        runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
        steps:
            - name: Get code
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
            - name: Install NodeJS
              uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                node-version: 10
            - name: Install dependancies
              run: NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 npm install
            - name: Check Nodejs 
              run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db
            - name: Build project
              run: NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 npm run build
            - name: Check the files in build folder
              run: |
                cd /home/runner/work/simple_App/simple_App/build/
                ls -l
            - name: Deploy to the server.
              run: scp -i ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }} -r * centos@18.191.60.170:/var/www/html/
```

error:

> cd /home/runner/work/uniconnect_ui/uniconnect_ui/build/
> ls -l
> scp -i ***
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> *** -r * centos@18.191.60.170:/var/www/html/
> shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
> total 280
> -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   6773 Sep 16 18:15 asset-manifest.json
> -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 260158 Sep 16 18:12 favicon.ico
> -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   4820 Sep 16 18:15 index.html
> -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker    317 Sep 16 18:12 manifest.json
> drwxr-xr-x 5 runner docker   4096 Sep 16 18:15 static
> KEY-----: No such file or directory
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I tried various method. But it is not fixed. How do I fix that?